# ASP.NET DrillThrough event in reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have added a reportviewer to my page :

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="repViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" OnDrillthrough="repViewer_Drillthrough"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Reports are loading fine, but when I click on a drillthrough column (a link), the report seems to reload (navigation buttons of the report go disabled and enabled again), but that's it, the OnDrillthrough event is not triggered (the breakpoint is not reached).

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

After playing a bit more with the control, I've noticed that nothing actually works. Paging, Searching, DrillingThrough, you name it... The report goes disabled and enabled again, but it always shows the same set of data (first page basically...)

One more thing. I don't have the report locally in my website. I use the ReportViewer to access remote reports. The code-behind is as follow:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        repViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        repViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://mssql/reportserver");
        repViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Domiciliations/myreport";
        repViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Does the report have a file extension of .rdl or .rdlc?  Are you catching any errors?

Comment: When you run the report on the report server (SSRS host) does it work correctly? (ie, is the error only happening with reportviewer)?

Comment: yes, on the server it works absolutely fine. This problem only occurs when running the report inside the reportviewer.

Comment: Are you running any of this through a proxy or gateway (like RSA) or SharePoint or some other wrapper that will re-write the URL?  I encountered this same thing when I ran reports through AquaLogic (a web wrapper/proxy that provided a security layer in front of my asp.net stuff).

Comment: yes, I do have a URL rewrite module. But I've disabled it because I thought the problem might come from that. It doesn't change anything. When I interact with the report (paging, searching,...) I can see javascript being downloaded, so it's definitely not rewriting url's.

Comment: The problem is: the javascript that is behind the reports also contains URLs.  SSRS generates them in a tricky manner so they don't get scraped-out by anti-pop-up add-ins.  Some of those js files refer to other js files, etc.  You might want to try using fiddler.  It will help you un-ravel the stack of file/script references.

Comment: I use chrome network traffic watcher, that spots everything I think. I haven't noticed any 404 or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

I just spotted the problem.  Each time the page loads, you are re-binding the report and wiping any additional state changes.  You should only initialize it when the page is not posting back.  Try this instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack())
    {
        repViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        repViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://mssql/reportserver");
        repViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Domiciliations/myreport";
        repViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: eeeeeehhhhh, I can't believe I forgot about that good old fashion IsPostback ! I've being doing ASP.NET MVC for a few years and I have not used that function for ages. I'm not at work right now so I can't test, but that sounds very much like the solution to my problem. I'll get back to you as soon as I've tried. Well-spotted !